# bash: jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/superauth?useSSL=false: No such file or directory

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm trying to connect Minecraft "superauth" plugin into my database, but i get errors.

Minecraft Console Error:

> Cannot connect to MySQL DataBase:
> [08:03:59 ERROR]: xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:
> [08:03:59 ERROR]: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:597)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:576)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.HikariDataSource.(HikariDataSource.java:81)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.global.storage.MySQLDataBase.(MySQLDataBase.java:41)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.bungee.SuperAuth$1.(SuperAuth.java:143)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.bungee.SuperAuth.loadSettings(SuperAuth.java:143)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.bungee.SuperAuth.onPluginEnable(SuperAuth.java:56)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.bungee.BungeePlugin.onEnable(BungeePlugin.java:81)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugins(PluginManager.java:287)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:322)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:41)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:27)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:
> [08:03:59 ERROR]: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:819)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:440)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       ... 11 more
> [08:03:59 ERROR]: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:
> [08:03:59 ERROR]: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:150)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:166)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:121)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:939)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:809)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       ... 19 more
> [08:03:59 ERROR]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       ... 22 more
> [08:03:59 INFO]: [SuperAuth]: Cannot execute MySQL Connection Call:
> [08:03:59 ERROR]: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.libs.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection()" because "this.dataSource" is null
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.global.storage.MySQLDataBase.connect(MySQLDataBase.java:92)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.global.users.UserStorage.preloadTables(UserStorage.java:244)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.global.users.UserStorage.(UserStorage.java:26)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.bungee.SuperAuth.onPluginEnable(SuperAuth.java:58)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at xyz.theprogramsrc.superauth.supercoreapi.bungee.BungeePlugin.onEnable(BungeePlugin.java:81)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugins(PluginManager.java:287)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:322)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:41)
> [08:03:59 ERROR]:       at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:27)

Plugin configuration:

> Prefix: '&9SuperAuth»&r'
> Language: en
> VPNBlockerEnabled: true
> AuthServer: brightmc
> BlockedActions:
> SERVER_CHANGE
> Commands:
> Premium: premium
> Cracked: cracked
> Permissions:
> PremiumCommand: command.premium
> CrackedCommand: command.cracked
> EnabledCommands:
> PREMIUM
> CRACKED
> MySQL:
> Host:
> Port: '3306'
> DataBase:
> UserName:
> Password:
> UseSSL: true
> ConnectionUrl: jdbc:mysql://{Host}:{Port}/{Database}?useSSL={UseSSL}

It wasn't working, so i pasted the jdbc:mysql... line into command prompt, and it returned something like that:

> root@instance-20230806-2133:/home/ubuntu# jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/superauth?useSSL=false
> bash: jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/superauth?useSSL=false: No such file or directory
> (also used the 127.0.0.1 IP instead of localhost)

never worked with databases before, idk what to do

Comment: the stack trace says `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused `. Make sure the database is available.

Comment: What is the point of trying to execute the JDBC URL on the bash prompt? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The error means you don't have MySQL running on localhost, port 3306.